# htaccess short url with emoving forward slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../menu.php?m=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

when someone goes to example.com/folder/text
will redirected to examle.com/menu.php?m=text
that's work fine,

but my problem is when someone write a forward slash or another folder

Ex: example.com/i/text/
it's redirected to examle.com/menu.php?m=text/ NOT to examle.com/menu.php?m=text

**so, my question can I remove all text after forward slash even if it's a file or folder**

Ex: example.com/i/folder/ OR example.com/i/folder/ssw/text.html
will redirected  to examle.com/menu.php?m=folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$` and use a negate character class like `[^/]+`:

```sh
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]+) ../menu.php?m=$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache completely before testing this change. This assumes that this .htaccess is inside a sub-directory and `menu.php` is in site root.